# Python packages causing apt errors

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, mysql, anaconda

I'm new to Ubuntu (16.04) and I'm getting this same error when I'm using the apt. It started when I installed MySQL by downloading the APT repository and using dpkg. I purged MySQL after but I'm still constantly getting this output. I have the default python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 and also anaconda with 3.6.2. I guessed that this error was resulting from conflicting python versions but I have no idea why it only started after I installed MySQL.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
name@xyz:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-pymysql (0.7.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pymysql (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-decorator (4.0.6-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-decorator (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-ptyprocess (0.5-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-ptyprocess (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pexpect:
 python-pexpect depends on python-ptyprocess; however:
  Package python-ptyprocess is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pexpect (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-simplegeneric (0.8.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-simplegeneric (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ipython:
 ipython depends on python-decorator; however:
  Package python-decorator is not configured yet.
 ipython depends on python-pexpect; however:
  Package python-pexpect is not configured yet.
 ipython depends on python-simplegeneric; however:
  Package python-simplegeneric is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ipython (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-markupsafe (0.23-2build2) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-markupsafe (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-jinja2:
 python-jinja2 depends on python-markupsafe; however:
  Package python-markupsafe is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-jinja2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-pycurl (7.43.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pycurl (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tornado:
 python-tornado depends on python-pycurl; however:
  Package python-pycurl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-tornado (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-zmq (15.2.0-0ubuntu4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-zmq (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ipython-notebook:
 ipython-notebook depends on ipython (= 2.4.1-1); however:
  Package ipython is not configured yet.
 ipython-notebook depends on python-jinja2; however:
  Package python-jinja2 is not configured yet.
 ipython-notebook depends on python-tornado (>= 3.1.0); however:
  Package python-tornado is not configured yet.
 ipython-notebook depends on python-zmq (>= 2.1.11); however:
  Package python-zmq is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ipython-notebook (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pymysql
 python-decorator
 python-ptyprocess
 python-pexpect
 python-simplegeneric
 ipython
 python-markupsafe
 python-jinja2
 python-pycurl
 python-tornado
 python-zmq
 ipython-notebook
 python-pkg-resources
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's the output requested in the comments:

```
name@xyz:~$ apt-cache policy python-minimal
python-minimal:
  Installed: 2.7.11-1
  Candidate: 2.7.11-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

name@xyz:/usr/share/python/debpython$ dpkg -S version.py
python3-minimal: /usr/share/python3/debpython/version.py
python-minimal: /usr/share/python/debpython/version.py
python3-checkbox-support: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/lib/conversion.py
dh-python: /usr/share/dh-python/dhpython/version.py
python3-checkbox-support: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/checkbox_support/parsers/tests/test_version.py
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64: /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py
ipython: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/version.py
python3-defer: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/version.py
python3-dbus: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_version.py
python3-setuptools: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py
libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/version.py
ibus-table: /usr/share/ibus-table/setup/version.py
python-zmq: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/tests/test_version.py
python3-pip: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py
python3-pkg-resources: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py
python-pkg-resources: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py
python-zmq: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/version.py
ajay@AJB-UX330UAK:/usr/share/python/debpython$ ^C
```

Comment: Have you run: sudo apt-get update before you ran upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also got this error when I downloaded unrelated software (VLC) even though VLC itself seemed to have installed fine.

Comment: Please show us the output of `dpkg -S /usr/share/python/debpython/version.py` and `apt-cache policy python-minimal`